# Definition without recursion, by cases, in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to define a unary operation on a set `stalk x`, whose typical elements are of the form `germ x U s`. In this case, there is no way to define an operation on general things of the same type as `germ x U s` in a way that reduces to what I want, so it seems like I really do have to resort to a definition by cases. I attempted the following

```
definition stalk_mop2 :: "'a ⇒( ('a set × 'a) set ⇒ ('a set × 'a) set ) " where
"stalk_mop2 x  y  = ( (λ z . if (∃ U s. y= germ x U s ) then 
(germ x U ( -⇩a ⇘objectsmap U⇙ s ) ) else undefined) z ) " ,
```

and got the error message that `U s` are extra variables on the RHS. It seems like by using this syntax Isabelle does not make the connection between the `if` hypothesis and the following term, so that although I did bind `U` and `s` in the conditional statement, it apparently interprets the next occurrences of `U` and `s` (after `then`) as free variables.

What I really want is just a function that takes `x` and something of the form `germ x U s` and returns `germ x U ( -⇩a ⇘objectsmap U⇙ s )`. Nothing here is recursive.

Is there a way around this problem, or maybe a better way to make definitions by cases that will allow me to define what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that this is nothing strange about Isabelle's syntax but, there just is no connection between the if-condition and the then- and else-branches. The scope of the existential quantifier naturally ends with `then`.

If you want to obtain a witness for something you know exists, you can use Hilbert's choice operator, e.g., `SOME (U, s). y = germ x U s)` gives you a pair `(U, s)` that satisfies `y = germ x U s` if such a pair exists (which you made sure by your if-condition), and is undefined otherwise.

So how about:

```
definition stalk_mop2 :: "'a ⇒(('a set × 'a) set ⇒ ('a set × 'a) set)"
where
  "stalk_mop2 x y  = ((λz .
    if ∃U s. y = germ x U s then
      let (U, s) = (SOME (U, s). y = germ x U s) in
      germ x U (-⇩a ⇘objectsmap U⇙ s)
    else undefined) z)"
```

**Update:** You can use multiple `let`s in one of the following ways

```
let x1 = e1 in let x2 = e2 in ...
```

or

```
let x1 = e1; x2 = e2; ... in ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, been stuck for a while trying to find a decent way and didn't realise Isabelle would say "so what?" if you just assume existence. Will keep the AoC in mind.

Comment: One silly question: if I want to "let" two things, something like let (U, s) = (SOME (U, s). y = germ x U s)  and let (V, t) = (SOME (V, t). z = germ x V t), what is the correct syntax? Apparentely just using "and" or the symbol doesn't work, but maybe I just don't get the syntax you used in your formulation to start with.